NextAuthentication(Developemnt) via mobile
when working on project; I often connect all my mobile devices to my laptop via private IP e.g 192.168.50.107:3000. This enables me to also view direct changes I make on my project form mobile screens adaptation.
Here comes the challenge, anytime I am working with authentication during development, I can't seem to authenticate in any of my mobile devices from the above above private IP address. Whenever I do, the address on my mobile browser reroutes itself to something like this localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google?state=DHTya which leads to "Safari cant open the page because it could not connect to the server
